# pipe zcat stdin into java program that takes multiple inputs

Tags: java, pipe, gzip, zcat

I have a gzipped file that is too large to unzip and save. I'm looking to use zcat to unzip it and feed it into a java program that takes in multiple inputs. This program has the format:

```
java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
   -T FastaAlternateReferenceMaker \
   -R refgen.fa \
   -o output.fasta \
   -V data.vcf
```

Where after -V is supposed to be the input from the gzipped file. I've tried something like:

```
zcat data.vcf.gz | java -jar GenomeAnalysisTK.jar \
   -T FastaAlternateReferenceMaker \
   -R refgen.fa \
   -o output.fasta \
   -V
```

But this does not work. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I suspect that the program is expecting a filename for `-V`. If that is the case, you might be able to stream a list of filenames on the command line, but not their contents. What does the documentation say?

Comment: I haven't found an answer when I read the documentation. This is the webpage: https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/documentation/tooldocs/org_broadinstitute_gatk_tools_walkers_fasta_FastaAlternateReferenceMaker.php