# using zcat to pass a gzipped file to a tool with options

Tags: command-line-arguments, gunzip, zcat, compressed-files

A question like this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513127/pipe-zcat-stdin-into-java-program-that-takes-multiple-inputs), but never answered.

I need to pass fastq files as options to a tool that does not accept gzipped inputs.  Is there really no option other than to unzip every one of them?

It fails when I pass the gzipped version:

```
mytool -s sample.fastq.gz -f fastq -o output
```

I've tried this, out of desperation (obviously doesn't work):

```
mytool -s <(zcat | sample.fastq.gz) -f fastq -o output
```

I can't pipe it directly, but is there an easier/more straightforward way than what I settled on below?

```
zcat sample.fastq.gz > sample.fastq
mytool -s sample.fastq -f fastq -o output
rm sample.fastq
```

It's slow and seems like a lot of unnecessary hassle for tons of files.  I'm not the best at coding and always up for learning new tricks.

Thanks!